# Top fixed Menubar, when linked to a certain div of the menu from another html

Tags: javascript

My problem is that i wanted to make a fixed menubar on top of the page when scrolled, that wasn't so hard, but the hard part for me is that, when i link it to a certain part  from the menubar from external html  the menubar shows up and it is fixed on the top of the page and it works perfectly when i scroll down, but when i scroll up, it stays there

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SMINT Demo</title>

<meta name = "keywords" content = "" />
<meta name = "description" content = "" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1 user-scalable=no">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.smint.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.subMenu').smint({
        'scrollSpeed' : 1000
    });
});

 (function(){

        $.fn.smint = function( options ) {

            // adding a class to users div
            $(this).addClass('smint');

            var settings = $.extend({
                'scrollSpeed '  : 500
                }, options);

            return $('.smint a').each( function() {


                if ( settings.scrollSpeed ) {

                    var scrollSpeed = settings.scrollSpeed;

                }

                ///////////////////////////////////

                // get initial top offset for the menu 
                var stickyTop = $('.smint').offset().top; 

                // check position and make sticky if needed
                var stickyMenu = function(){

                    // current distance top
                    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 

                    // if we scroll more than the navigation, change its position to fixed and add class 'fxd', otherwise change it back to absolute and remove the class
                    if (scrollTop > stickyTop) { 
                        $('.smint').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0 }).addClass('fxd');

                        } else {
                            $('.smint').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top':stickyTop }).removeClass('fxd'); 
                        }   
                };

                // run function
                stickyMenu();

                // run function every time you scroll
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                     stickyMenu();
                });

                ///////////////////////////////////////

                $(this).on('click', function(e){


                    // gets the height of the users div. This is used for off-setting the scroll so th emenu doesnt overlap any content in the div they jst scrolled to
                    var selectorHeight = $('.smint').height();   

                    // stops empty hrefs making the page jump when clicked
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // get id pf the button you just clicked
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');

                    // gets the distance from top of the div class that matches your button id minus the height of the nav menu. This means the nav wont initially overlap the content.
                    var goTo =  $('div.'+ id).offset().top -selectorHeight;

                    // Scroll the page to the desired position!
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: goTo }, scrollSpeed);

                }); 
            });

        };

    })();
function showImage(imgName) {
                document.getElementById('largeImg').src = imgName;
                showLargeImagePanel();
                unselectAll();
            }
            function showLargeImagePanel() {
                document.getElementById('largeImgPanel').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
            function unselectAll() {
                if(document.selection) document.selection.empty();
                if(window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            }
            function hideMe(obj) {
                obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }

</script>

<style>
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0;}
body {

    color: #f8e0b3;
    font-size: 12px;
    background:#f8e0b3;

}
h1, h2 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin:0 0 15px 0;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    line-height: 100%;

}
h1.title {
    font-size: 46px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f8e0b3;


}
h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
.menuBtn {
    background: center center no-repeat transparent;
    background: #f8e0b3;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.wrap {
        /*background:url(../images/bg.png) top left repeat-x;*/
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1140px;
        min-width: 960px;
        z-index: 10;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
}
.section {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    min-width: 960px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.inner {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding:30px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding:30px 0;
}
/* This is the selector i used for my menu, it needs to be set as position:absolute; */
.subMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    min-width: 960px;
    background: #ff0000; /*за главна категория */
}
.subMenu .inner {
    padding:0;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.subNavBtn {
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    width: 8%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 15px 2% 0 2%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
.end {
    margin: 0;
}
/* SECTIONS */
.sTop {
    min-height: 630px;
    background:#f8e0b3;
    color:#3d3d3d;
}
.s1 {
    min-height: 500px;
    background: #f8e0b3;
}


.s2 {
      min-height: 500px;
    background: #f8e0b3;
}


.s3 {
     min-height: 500px;
    background: #f8e0b3;
}


.s4 {
      min-height: 500px;
    background: #f8e0b3;
}

.s5 {
     min-height: 500px;
    background: #f8e0b3;
}
.s6 {
    min-height: 500px;
    background: #f8e0b3; 
}
.s7 {
     min-height: 500px;
    background: #f8e0b3;
}
h1.border {
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 10px;
                border-color: #ff0000;
        }
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
        }         
        p.border {
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 10px;
                border-color: #ff0000;
        }
            p {
                text-align: center;
        } 

        #largeImgPanel {
                text-align: center;
                visibility: hidden;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 100;
                top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
                background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);
            }
            #displayImage{
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: red;
            }      
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">

      <div class="subMenu" >
        <div class="inner">
            <a href="#" id="sTop" class="subNavBtn">Блузи</a> 
            <a href="#" id="s1" class="subNavBtn">Ризи </a>
            <a href="#" id="s2" class="subNavBtn"> Сака</a>
            <a href="#" id="s3" class="subNavBtn">Аксесоари</a>
            <a href="#" id="s4" class="subNavBtn">Якета</a>
            <a href="#" id="s5" class="subNavBtn">Панталони/Дънки</a>
            <a href="#" id="s6" class="subNavBtn">Обувки</a>
            <a href="#" id="s7" class="subNavBtn end">Спортни стоки</a>
        </div>
    </div>   

    <div class="section sTop">

        <div class="inner"><img src="heading.jpg" alt="заглавие">
            <h1 class="border">Област Пловдив</h1>
            <p class="border">Мъжки блузи</p>          

        </div>
        <br class="clear">
    </div>      
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/bluzi s kus dulag rukav/2.jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show">
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/bluzi s kus dulag rukav/3.jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show"> 
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/bluzi s kus dulag rukav/4.jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show">    
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/bluzi s kus dulag rukav/5.jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show">    
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/bluzi s kus dulag rukav/6.jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show">

       <div class="section s1">

           <h1 class="border"><font color="black"><a name="mujkirizi">Ризи</a><font></h1>
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/rizi/hm (1).jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show">

       </div>

        <div class="section s2">  

            <h1 class="border"><font color="black"><a name="mujkisaka">Сака</a><font></h1>
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/rizi/hm (1).jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show">

    </div>

    <div class="section s3">

        <h1 class="border"><font color="black"><a name="mujkiaksesoari"> Аксесоари</a><font></h1>
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/rizi/hm (1).jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show">

    </div>

    <div class="section s4">

        <h1 class="border"><font color="black"><a name="mujkiiaketa"> Якета</a><font></h1>
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/rizi/hm (1).jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show">

    </div>  

    <div class="section s5">

        <h1 class="border"><font color="black"><a name="mujkipantaloni"> Панталони/Дънки</a><font></h1>
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/rizi/hm (1).jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show">

    </div> 

        <div class="section s6">

            <h1 class="border"><font color="black"><a name="mujkiobuvki"> Обувки</a><font></h1>
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/rizi/hm (1).jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show">

    </div> 

        <div class="section s7">

            <h1 class="border"><font color="black"><a name="mujkisportnistoki"> Спортни стоки</a><font></h1>
        <img id="displayImage"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(this.src)" src="hm/mujko/rizi/hm (1).jpg" width="200" height="200" name="show">

    </div> 
        <div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="hideMe(this);">
            <img id="largeImg" style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;" />

        </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, it's fixed when i scroll down, and when i come back on the top of the page it goes where it was at the beginning, i don't get your problem, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be more specific, i have the menubar that is fixed when i scroll down or up and it work perfectly when i open this specific html. This menubar contain 7 submenus and my idea is that when i use an external html with link to for example submenu 3 using  (it  opens this specific html and scroll down to submenu 3)but the menubar doesnt move when i scroll up , it only works(stay fixed at the top)when i scroll down